# command not found but file exists

Tags: virtualbox

I know this has been a common problem but the answers provided to other questions haven't helped with my current issue.

When trying to run a file called srf2obj I get the "command not found" response.

I can see that the file is there. "file srf2obj" returns:
GNU awk script, ASCII text executable

OS is installed on Virtualbox.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What answers have you tried?

Comment: You may need to install the package "build-essential" on Ubuntu. It includes everything you need to compile and make.

Comment: Make sure it's executable, and then run it like this: `./srf2obj`

Answer (score 4):

When you type `srf2obj`, the shell checks to see if `srf2obj` is an alias, a shell function, or (this is what you want to happen) an executable file in one of the directories in your `$PATH`, or, if you specify a path to the file (`/home/walt/bin/foo`, `./srf2obj`) it will try that.

If `ls -l srf2obj` shows that it is executable, try typing `./srf2obj`. If not, make it executable via `chmod +x srf2obj`. If you are going to do this a lot, consider adding this directory to your `$PATH`.

Or, you could invoke the interpreter directly, thusly: `gawk srf2obj`

Comment: It is common that Linux does not check if the file resists in the current directory?

Comment: No, it's avoiding a security vulnerability. "`luser`: Hey `root`, `cd` to my home directory - something strange...". `root`:`cd /home/luser;ls` - if `.` is in `$PATH`, and `luser` has an executable version of a file called `ls` in the current directory, `luser` wins, `root` loses.